# React - Redux - Only some data is displayed

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm sure this is a simple question, but actually I can't figure out, why it is not working. I'm still in beginner with `react-redux`, so please be patient with me. ;-)

I'm loading different data with `react-redux`. Now I want to fill a `select` box with the loaded values.

I can see the data is loaded correctly (`props.anreden` & `props.benutzer`). So I can be sure that the data is loaded correctly and I have error somewhere else.

[image]

The difference is that `anreden` is an obejct-array, while `benutzer` is an object.

When I want to fill the `select` box in the `render()` method, it fills only the data of `benutzer` and not of `anreden`:

[image]

This is the code of this part:

```
<div className="select">
    <select
        value={0}                
        className={`form-control tabable`}
    >
        <option value={0}>auswählen</option>
        <option value={this.props.benutzer.id}>{this.props.benutzer.vorname}</option>
        {this.props.anreden && this.props.anreden.length > 0 &&
        this.props.anreden.map((option) => {
            return (<option value={option.id}>{option.bezeichnung}</option>)
        })}
    </select>
</div>
```

Does anyone have a hint for me, why it is like this?

Comment: Are you including all those redux state values in mapStateToProps?

Comment: `this.props.anreden` are you sure its an array, you can verify using console.log

Comment: It is not related to Redux. Also provide what console says. Probably because you did not provide key attribute `<option value={option.id} key={option.id}>{option.bezeichnung}</option> `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `this.props.anreden` is an Object, not an array as you expect it to be. So `this.props.anreden.length > 0` is always `false`.

Map over values. Also you need keys.

```
{this.props.anreden && 
    Object.values(this.props.anreden).map((option) => {
        return (<option value={option.id} key={option.id}>{option.bezeichnung}</option>)
    })}
```

Comment: @dns_nx Glad I could help :)